# Jdewit Timepicker show widget on text and icon click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this widget to show even when I click the textbox.
How can I achieve this ?
I using jdewit timepicker

here my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small/>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({ minuteStep: 15 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to archive this by using .trigger

here my code

### HTML

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small/>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({ minuteStep: 5 });
$('#timepicker1').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next().trigger('click');
}) ;
```